# clisp ed command runs notepad but my favorite editor

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I'm using clisp on Windows8.1 64bit. The problem is that when I type 
`(ed "filename")`, notepad comes foreground and I need to edit the file with it.

Since I've already installed vim and configured `PATH` (It's `C:\vim`),
I want to edit them in vim as I do in linux systems.

So, how can I run vim from clisp ed command?

Answer (score 2):

Set `*editor*` in your `.clisp` or `EDITOR` in your environment.

This is described in the [Fine Manual](http://clisp.org/impnotes/debugger.html#ed).

(You now owe me [1 zorkmid](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-fine)).